# Comparing Apple's aluminum keyboards, wired compact vs wireless

Tags: keyboard

I never thought I would replace my old Apple Extended II, but after getting a Wired Keyboard with my Mac I found it to be a great alternative - and with all those Eject and volume keys...

But it's big. Big enough that I'm always hitting the right side of it when I'm gaming. Wide enough that I want to try something else. So I got the Apple Wireless Keyboard. It uses someone else's mechanism for the keys, and they are harder to push and mushy. My typo rate soared so I returned it.

So, I'm thinking of getting the Compact Wired version. Has anyone reading this used the Compact Wired, current Apple Wired AND the Wireless versions and can compare them? Is the Compact Wired's mechanism the same as the one in the larger wired, or the wireless? It's this one:

[image]

Comment: You'd have to prise my wired extended from my cold, dead fingers. Fortunately I've learned where the letters are, as most of the graphic has worn off. I'm interested in the answer, though, in case I ever do need to replace/swap.

Comment: If you mean Extended II with ADB, poke around at electronics resellers - like Active Surplus in Toronto. They often have stacks of them.

Comment: eek, no, not that old, it's an aluminium, USB, circa 08. Feels a bit like a lappy keyboard, but so much smoother. My last one had ADB though. Apple keyboards do seem to last a while ;)